# How to create the different size of EBS volume and attach to single EC2 instance using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ebs

I am creating multiple volumes with different sizes like below:

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  for_each = {
    0 = 100
    1 = 50
    2 = 20
    3 = 20
    4 = 50
  }
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  size              = each.value
  type              = "gp2"
}
```

I will create multiple volumes like the above. Now, I want to attach it to a single EC2 instance.
In below, resource **ec2_production** I am defining the configuration for **root volume** i.e. **size is 40GB and volume type is gp2**. Now I want to create 5 five more volume like mentioned in the above resource **ebs_volume** and attach them to my below-defined ec2_production instance

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_production" {
  count         = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.security_group_access_internet.id]
  key_name = "key-pair"
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 40
  }
  tags = {
    Name = var.tag
  }
}
```

This is the resource for the EBS_volume_attachment:

I am not sure how to pass the devices name and how to attach all the EBS volume to my AWS instance:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachement" {
  count       = "${var.ec2_instance_count * var.ebs_volume_count}"
  volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id[count.index]}"
  device_name = "${element(var.ec2_device_names, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.ec2_production.*.id, count.index)}"

}
```

My variable.tf file

```
variable "ec2_device_names" {
    default = [
    "/dev/sdf",
    "/dev/sdg",
    "/dev/sdh",
    "/dev/sdi",
    "/dev/sdj"
  ]
}

variable "ec2_instance_count" {
  default = 1
}

variable "ec2_instance_type" {
  default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "ami" {
    default = "ami-0d382e80be7ffdae5"
}
```

Is there any way I can attach all the volume to each device I have created above and attach to my EC2 instance?

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: @Marcin sorry for the bad format of the comment

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error formatted properly rather than leaving it in the comments.

Comment: Please always include the relevant error messages in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count             = var.instance_count * var.volume_count
  availability_zone = aws_instance.ec2[count.index < var.volume_count ? 0 : 1 ].availability_zone
  size              = var.additional_volume_size[count.index%var.volume_count]
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachement" {
  count       = var.instance_count * var.volume_count
  volume_id   = element(aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id, count.index)
  device_name = element(var.device_name, count.index)
  instance_id = element(aws_instance.ec2.*.id, count.index < var.volume_count ? 0 : 1)
  force_detach = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First I think your `aws_ebs_volume` is wrongly named in the question but this might be just a copy & paste error, it should be `resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume"` not `resource "aws_ebs_volume" "for_each"`.

Second in your `aws_volume_attachment` you're accessing the `ebs_volume` index incorrectly, you want to do `volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume[count.index].id`, i.e. access the list of `ebs_volume` at the `count.index` position and then get the attribute `id`.

Thirdly your `count` in the `aws_volume_attachment` is iterating over too much and the `instance_id` can be fixed.

So your updated code for the `aws_volume_attachment` should look like:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachement" {
  count       = var.ebs_volume_count
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume[count.index].id
  device_name = "${element(var.ec2_device_names, count.index)}"
  instance_id = aws_instance.ec2_production.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Now I have updated my question with more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the attachment of EBS to instance/instances.
After that, you need to mount ones.
I have a small [cheatsheet](https://github.com/abdibus/Terraform-Cheatsheet/tree/master/AWS-EBS-Attach-Mount) for one Instance-EBS you may use.